# Javascript in a node via CK Editor

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I am using CK Editor (version:'4.3.3',revision:'7841b02') with Drupal (core: 7.26) via the WYSIWYG module (7.x-2.2). I'm also using Workbench (7.x-1.2) and Workbench Moderation (7.x-1.3), which may or may not be involved.

I have a node that contains a 'rating' widget from a third-party company in the form of Javascript between "script" tags.

When I edit the node and add this code, it works. I can see the widget and it functions.

But when I go to edit the node again, the script code is not visible in the editor. If I cancel the draft creation, it is still there and functions. If I save the draft (without makeing any changes) it's gone from the draft but still there in the published version. If I publish the draft of course it's gone.

I'm also using drush to sync instances and when I sync down from dev (where it's working) to my local instance, it does not work in my local instance.

In the config I have Verify HTML off, because it says it removes 'malicious' tags, which I would guess includes "script". I've looked over the config and can't see anything else that might affect this.

Has anyone else had this issue? And ideas on where to look for clues would be appreciated.

Also looking at adding it via and include in a single-node template, but wondering if this could work directly in the node content.

Comment: I would put the code in a separate js file and include it on the required pages to avoid keeping it the DB at all. Any code in the db is hard to maintain and tends to just lead to more headaches further down the road (plus you will avoid this issue entirely :)

Comment: I did end up doing this. Created a node template for the node where this resides and included it there. Not sure why I was making it harder on myself than it needed to be. Thanks for your response, Felix!